# Jmeter start test run from command line and get result

Tags: jmeter

I want to execute jmeter from command line and get the result on screeen. I am using following command for this,

```
jmeter -n -t "D:\\apache-jmeter-4.0\\bin\\Test.jmx" -l result.jtl
```

This command displays the result on screen on summary format like below,

```
summary +      1 in     2s =    0.5/s Avg:  1917 Min:  1917 Max:  1917 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 10 Started: 10 Finished: 0
summary +     99 in     6s =   17.9/s Avg:   482 Min:   203 Max:  2009 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 10 Finished: 10
summary =    100 in     6s =   18.1/s Avg:   497 Min:   203 Max:  2009 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

And data in result.jtl is

```
2018/06/05 20:34:58.307,1917,Home Page,200,OK,Thread Group 1-9,text,true,138969,629
2018/06/05 20:34:58.278,2001,Home Page,200,OK,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,138969,658
......
```

I read in document that Jmeter calculates the summary from this data to display on screen and raw data is directed and stored to result.jtl file. But I want to get the same raw data on console which I may pick for further custom checks and calculation. Is it possible to get the result.jtl data on screen ? if yes, please suggest me how it can be achieved.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? you just want to view it on console?

Comment: yes @user7294900. I just want to get the result on console. Once result data is available in console, i will take it for further analysis on the fly. I will be executing command from node.js.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to print .jtl file contents into terminal you can use [`type`](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html) or [`more`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command)#Examples) commands like:

```
type result.jtl
```

[image: JMeter View jtl file]

You might also be interested in [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) which allows generation of different tables and charts basing on .jtl results file from command line.

Also be aware that according to [JMeter Best Pratices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you should always use the latest JMeter version (JMeter 4.0 as of now) as newer versions normally contain bug fixes, performance improvements and new features and JMeter 2.11 is 4+ years old. For example since JMeter 3.0 it is possible to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html).

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri. The "type" solution will work but i would prefer to get data in stream. Thanks for suggesting to upgrade Jmeter.

Comment: I have upgraded my jmeter to 4.0 latest version but there also no such option available.